# GlobalParametersUpdateScript.ps1 is resetting Azure Data Factory Public Network Access

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-virtual-network, azure-deployment

I have Azure Data Factory CI/CD pipeline. My ADF have few global params, so I am following Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-global-parameters) for their CI/CD. On same [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-global-parameters) page, there is below 'Update global param' powershell script. Issue is whenever this script runs, it resets my ADF network access to 'Public endpoint' from 'private endpoint'.

```
param
(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [String] $globalParametersFilePath,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [String] $resourceGroupName,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [String] $dataFactoryName
)

Import-Module Az.DataFactory

$newGlobalParameters = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[string,Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.GlobalParameterSpecification]'

Write-Host "Getting global parameters JSON from: " $globalParametersFilePath
$globalParametersJson = Get-Content $globalParametersFilePath

Write-Host "Parsing JSON..."
$globalParametersObject = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($globalParametersJson)

# $gp in $factoryFileObject.properties.globalParameters.GetEnumerator()) 
# may  be used in case you use non-standard location for global parameters. It is not recommended. 
foreach ($gp in $globalParametersObject.GetEnumerator()) {
    Write-Host "Adding global parameter:" $gp.Key
    $globalParameterValue = $gp.Value.ToObject([Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.GlobalParameterSpecification])
    $newGlobalParameters.Add($gp.Key, $globalParameterValue)
}

$dataFactory = Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $dataFactoryName
$dataFactory.GlobalParameters = $newGlobalParameters

Write-Host "Updating" $newGlobalParameters.Count "global parameters."

Set-AzDataFactoryV2 -InputObject $dataFactory -Force
```

I want Network access to be via 'Private endpoint' ALWAYS. Does anyone faced this issue?
[image: Azure Data Factory Network Access]

Answer (score 0):

Just change last line of your Global param script as follows:

```
Set-AzDataFactoryV2 -InputObject $dataFactory -PublicNetworkAccess "Disabled" -Force
```

Now your ADF network access won't reset to Public one.